# Capital letters in product composition?

Tags: capitalization

I am trying to find out why I see product composition written with capital letters, such as 70% Polycarbonate 20% Silicone 10% Thermoplastic Elastomer. Why is that? Is there an official rule or is it like this to make it look better?

Thanks for all answers.